# Removing some html tags using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove some html tags like ***td*** and ***a href*** using javascript. The data is a ajax returned table data on which I want to perform these operation before showing it on a div in browser page.
    
***1.*** I want to remove 4th and 5th column of the table (i.e. Stamps and Status)
    
***2.*** I also want to remove 'a href' tag (along with javascript it contains) from the first column of the row of the table, so that only "Sukhvinder Singh GUJRAL" would remain there.

Here is the code

The headers are:

```
<table width=0 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1><font>
<tr bgcolor=silver align=center>
<th><font style="font-size: 10pt">Name</th>
<th width=60><font style="font-size: 9pt">Entry<br>info</th>
<th width=40><font style="font-size: 9pt">Instant Messaging</th>
<th width=30><font style="font-size: 9pt">Stamps</th>
<th width=40><font style="font-size: 9pt">Status</th>
</tr>
```

There is just one row in the table, but I am giving example of that row:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align=center>
<td align=left><font><a href="javascript:ed_fct('st-eduid%3Ded243547%2Cou%3Dpeople%2Cdc%3Dst%2Cdc%3Dcom')" onmouseover="return true" onmouseout="return true">Sukhvinder Singh GUJRAL</a>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font>&nbsp;<font style="font-size: 8pt">ST person</font>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font color=red>N/A</font>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font><a href="javascript:usm_fct('./Stamping_View/user_stamping_view.php','st-eduid%3Ded243547%2Cou%3Dpeople%2Cdc%3Dst%2Cdc%3Dcom')" onmouseover="return true" onmouseout="return true">stamp</a>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font><font style="color: green">Active</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You didn't said what you tried in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you want to remove the link alone ...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following JS fiddle for the answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/JLVML/

You can use the following code to remove the anchor tags

```
$("a").replaceWith($("a").text());
```

Hope this helps for you.

Comment: thanks but i have many ahref on the page. How to catch this particular ahref tag. Should i catch it using the div on which i am displaying this table. My jquery is poor , but should it be something like this **$(parentdiv).child(table).a.replaceWith($("a").text());** Sorry for my bad jquery. I hope you get what i meant.

Comment: I understand your issue. I have edited the fiddle. here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/JLVML/1/
I have added an <div> tag around that to identify the table loading area. so any <a> tag inside that <div> will be removed.

Comment: Almost all 3 answers worked for me, but yours took me closest to solution . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below it will help you..

**Fiddle Example :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/125/

I have give ID to the Table as `tblinfo`

**JQuery :**

You have 5 columns so i have use `Slice()` to remove last two(4 and 5) columns..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tblinfo th").slice(-2).remove();
  $("#tblinfo td").slice(-2).remove();
   $('#tblinfo td a').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
   });
});
```

If you don't want the Table ID `tblinfo` then try like below

Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/126/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("th").slice(-2).remove();
  $("td").slice(-2).remove();
  $('td a').each(function(){
  $(this).contents().unwrap();
  });
});
```

Comment: This question is not tagged as `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful answer, but the problem is that i dont have "tblinfo" , and also i cannot use your second method since i have two tables on the page. Can I catch this particular table from the div in which I am showing it? I am not expert on jquery but something in natural language like :  **$(parentdiv).child(table).th.slice(-2).remove()** Sorry for my bad jquery

Comment: @user2261438: yes you can... add ID attribute to the Table you need.. just like this `<table width=0 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 id="tblinfo">` then you can catch the table by using my code...

Comment: Hey thanks, i used code for removing table columns. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are in a callback or something and that `xhr` is a reference to
the `XMLHttpRequest` object. The trick here is that we create a temporary detached `div` element and we set it's `innerHTML` property to `xhr.responseText`. We then modify the element **in memory** so that we do not cause multiple DOM reflows. http://jsfiddle.net/S7uK2/

```
var tempEl = document.createElement('div'),
    textNode = document.createTextNode(),
    els, i, el;

tempEl.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

//remove a tag
el = tempEl.querySelector('td:first-child a');
textNode.nodeValue = el.innerText;
el.parentNode.replaceChild(textNode, el);

//remove other elements
els = tempEl.querySelectorAll('th:nth-child(n+4), td:nth-child(n+4)');
i = els.length - 1;

while (i >= 0) {
    el = els[i];
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    i--;
}
```

At this point, `tempEl.innerHTML` contains the cleaned-up table markup and you can use it to show your table in the `DOM`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your wonderful reply but still I am confused.This is my ajax call using jquery ----   **$.post(
                    '/abc/xyz/search_user.php',
                    {abc:'param1'},
                    function(data)
                    {   //this is function where data is returned
                    },
                    'html'
                );** Can you explain me how to convert that returned data into responsetext?

Comment: @user2261438, is `data` the table's HTML? In the above code, I considered that `xhr.responseText` would be.

Comment: Thank you very much, learnt some new things from your code since i was a novice at jquery.